# I want to implement custom caching in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

The default caching mechanism in nsetjs doest not give enough flexibility as you can not annotate the individual [routes/methods](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/140) with `@Cache` directive or something like that.

I want to be able to set custom ttl as well as I do not want to cache every route.May be it is even make sense to move the caching to service level for that purpose, not sure yet.

Just wondering how would you do that in a better way withing nestjs framework. Just to cache a specific routes or service methods.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started working on a Caching module for NestJS after running into the same issues that you did. It's available on npm at `@nestjs-plus/caching` although it's not quite ready to be used yet I'll share the Interceptor definition here. It relies on the mixin pattern to be able to receive per route options.

```js
import { makeInjectableMixin } from '@nestjs-plus/common';
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Cache, CacheToken } from './cache';

@Injectable()
export abstract class CachingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  protected abstract readonly options: CacheOptions;

  constructor(@Inject(CacheToken) private readonly cache: Cache) {}

  async intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>
  ): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const http = context.switchToHttp();
    const request = http.getRequest();
    const key = this.options.getKey(request);

    const cached = await this.cache.get(key);
    if (cached != null) {
      return of(cached);
    }

    return call$.pipe(
      switchMap(result => {
        return forkJoin(
          of(result),
          this.cache.set(key, result, this.options.ttl)
        ).pipe(catchError(e => of(result)));
      }),
      map(([result, setOp]) => result)
    );
  }
}

export interface CacheOptions {
  ttl: number;
  getKey: (request) => string;
}

export const makeCacheInterceptor = (options: CacheOptions) => {
  return makeInjectableMixin('CachingInterceptor')(
    class extends CachingInterceptor {
      protected readonly options = options;
    }
  );
};

export interface Cache {
  get: (key: string) => Promise<any | null | undefined>;
  set: (key: string, data: any, ttl: number) => Promise<void>;
  del: (key: string) => Promise<void>;
}

export const CacheToken = Symbol('CacheToken');
```

This pattern allows the application of caching per route in your controllers with different TTLs or methods of extracting the cache key from an incoming request.

```js
@Get()
  @UseInterceptors(
    makeCacheInterceptor({
      getKey: () => '42' // could be req url, query params, etc,
      ttl: 5,
    }),
  )
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
```

The only thing missing from here (and the library I'm working on) is a flexible set of cache implementations such as in memory, redis, db etc. I plan on integrating with the cache-manager library to fill that gap this week (it's the same cache provider that Nest uses for the default Cache implementation). Feel free to use this as a base for creating your own or stay tuned for when `@nestjs-plus/caching` is ready to be used. I'll update this question later this week when I publish a production ready version.

Comment: Do you know of any way to make use of the inbuilt `@CacheTTL` decorator?

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to set the `TTL` (Expiration Time) and `CacheKey` at the route level in NestJS.

See the [global cache overrides](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#global-cache-overrides) section in the NestJS Docs on Caching.

A code snippet demonstrating the `@CacheKey` and `@CacheTTL` decorators that provide this feature:

```js
@Controller()
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @CacheKey('custom_key')
  @CacheTTL(20)
  findAll(): string[] {
    return [];
  }
}
```